# How to set maxlength for li tag to 5 in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
 selectPreviousSearch(index) {
        this.search = this.searchHistory[index];
        this.showSearchHistory = false;
      },
```

```html
   <input class="form-control bg-light-blue" id="SearchText"  type="text" v-model="search"
        @keydown.enter = 'enter'
        @click="onClick"
        
        @keyup.enter="processSearch"
        @input = 'change'
        @keyup="inputChanged"
        @keydown.down="onArrow"
        @keydown.up="onArrow"
    />
     <ul class="list-group" v-if="showSearchHistory">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory" :key="index"
              @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)">{{ item }}</li>
          </ul>
```

I want to set maxlength for li tag, so that only user can store only 5 items in search history.

Basically i am trying to create input field, in input field if user typed any character, The type character will store in list.

So for the li, i want to keep condition for storing only 5 items in selectPreviousSearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the most recent 5 entries, sorted from `most recent` to `least recent`, you can try

```js
v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory.slice(-5).reverse()"
```

---

Edited by @`taneeru dhanunjay`

```js
@keydown.space="preventLeadingSpace"
 preventLeadingSpace(e) {
      // only prevent the keypress if the value is blank
      if (!e.target.value) e.preventDefault();
      // otherwise, if the leading character is a space, remove all leading white-space
      else if (e.target.value[0]==' ') e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/^\s*/, "");
    },
```

Comment: Perfect, But It's Taking spaces also, how can i avoid spaces

Comment: When i click space bar and enter, Even  space also displaying

Comment: If you want to remove leading and trailing spaces, you can `trim()` the string. I've updated the answer with an example

Comment: I edited with trim it's working fine for search, and for search button initially if i click on search button space is reflecting, only for first time

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-icon" @click="processSearch"

this is the code for search button.

Comment: Method for it.

   processSearch() {
        if ( this.searchHistory.indexOf(this.search) === -1) {
          this.searchHistory.push(this.search);
        }
        this.search = '';
       
      },

Comment: This feels like it should be a separate question

Comment: Ok Thanks for your time, will add as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory.slice(searchHistory.length-5)

selectPreviousSearch(index) {
    index += searchHistory.length-5;
    index = index<0?0:index;
    this.search = this.searchHistory[index];
    this.showSearchHistory = false;
 },
```

Method 2:
change the function to keep last 5 input where you stored searchHistory.

```
onChange(newInput){
    searchHistory.length >=5 && searchHistory.shift();
    searchHistory.push(newInput);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine, Now its stopping near 5th value.  But now the issue is if i type 1,2,3,4,5 at 5th value it is stopping and not proceeding,iand if i enter 6th value it is not reflecting. So i need as recent entered value to be shown and want the same maxlength as 5.

Comment: v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory.slice(searchHistory.length-5)"